# How to calculate cumulative mean in R?

Tags: r

(I am sorry if the term is not correct).

In R, I have a numeric vector `x`. I want to create new vector `y` where:

`y[i] = mean (x[1:i)`

It is easy to write a function to calculate `y`, but is there a built-in function in R which do the task?

Thank you very much

Comment: `cummean` from `dplyr`. See `?cummean`

Comment: The answer below is actually better IMO than the current top answers at the linked question above (and because of which this was flagged as duplicate).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
y <- cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)
```

Reference
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/162729.html